# can we integrate fastapi-admin with sqlalchemy orm

Tags: sqlalchemy, admin, fastapi, polymorphic-associations

I want to setup fastapi-admin with sqlalchemy orm.
I googled but got articles for fastapi-admin with tortoise orm only.
Can we set up it using sqlalchemy becuse its supports polymorphic association.
Or any other solution for the same that how can we create a app using fastapi and sqlalchemy with any admin panel also.

Answer (score 2):

[SQLAlchemy Admin](https://aminalaee.github.io/sqladmin/) provides admin functionalities like the fastapi-admin or flask-admin backend panel. It was released just recently in January 2022, so I'm not sure if it already has feature parity.

The missing sqlalchemy admin panel for fastapi was the reason why I didn't migrate from flask to fastapi, but with the new SQLAlchemy-Admin I give it a try.

Comment: Can you share your experience?